# android: how do i preserve the data in my arrayadapter/listview when change orientation?

Tags: android, listview, orientation, listadapter

as above, is it done automatically? My list was empty once the orientation chMYanges? and nope, i need the orientation change =)

My adapter

```
public class ResultsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SearchItem> implements Filterable{

private ArrayList<SearchItem> subItems;
private ArrayList<SearchItem> allItems;// = new ArrayList<SearchItem>();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private PTypeFilter filter;
private OnCheckedChangeListener test;

public ResultsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<SearchItem> items,OnCheckedChangeListener a) {

    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        //this.subItems = items;
        for( int i = 0;i < items.size();i++){
            subItems.add(items.get(i));
        }
        this.allItems = this.subItems;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);

        test = a;
}
```

My onCreate

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        



    ListView lvr = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.search_results);



  //  if(savedInstanceState == null){
        this.m_adapter = new ResultsAdapter(home.this, R.layout.listrow, sResultsArr,home.this);
        this.specsAdapter = new FeaturesExpandableAdapter(home.this,new ArrayList<String>(),new ArrayList<ArrayList<Feature>>()); 
   // }
        lvr.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);
```

thanks guys

Comment: "perserve"? I first read "perverse" (sorry), but I guess you mean "preserve" ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can also use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Something like this in your Activity:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return this.m_adapter.getItems();
}
```

And then in your onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // more init stuff here

    sResultsArr = (ArrayList<SearchItems>)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if(sResultArr == null) {
        sResultsArray = new ArrayList<SearchItems>();  // or some other initialization
    }

    self.m_adapter = new ResultsAdapter(home.this, R.layout.listrow, sResultsArr,home.this);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Neither `ArrayAdapter` nor its parent classes have a `getItems` method.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that on recent Android Releases (at least 4.0) this practice is highly discouraged.

Comment: Then whats the new method?

Comment: @MattHuggins use `getItemsArrayList()`. Solution worked for me.

Comment: @Mgamerz Why ? Can you elaborate a bit more? The solution is effective and simple.

Answer (score 5):

If you have data in memory that needs to stick around during an orientation change, you need to do something to arrange that. The best solution is to implement `onSaveInstanceState()` and use it to store your data, because that gets used not only for orientation changes, but other situations as well (e.g., your activity is on the current stack, but it needs to get kicked out of RAM to free up space for things later in the stack).

Comment: onsaveinstancestate i can only save name-value pairs.. may i know how do i keep the actual object itself?

Comment: Via `onSaveInstanceState()`, you can't, because your process may be destroyed (see the e.g. in my answer). You can use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to hold onto an arbitrary object during an orientation change, but bear in mind that this pretty much *only* handles orientation changes, not scenarios where your activity is evicted from RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the wrong way. Please take some time to see this video from Android's developers: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70 (about 1 hour).

I followed the video, and my list view works fine when screen changes orientation  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using `OnSaveInstanceState()` and `OnRestoreInstanceState()`

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        name_array.addAll(state.getStringArrayList("key"));
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putStringArrayList("key",name_array);
    }
```

`name_array` is hold in `ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this ,R.layout.item,name_array);`

Now when you change from landscape to portrait and reverse, data aren't los

Answer (score -1):

The data should not be lost when you change the orientation. The only thing I can imagine is that the layout for your activity is not correct, like, controls move out of the visible area upon changing the orientation.

Comment: This seems highly possible- or perhaps the data that is being used to populate the list gets destroyed along with the along with the activity on the orientation change but does not get recreated?

Comment: hi thorsten,
is it due to the fact that i actually used a custom arrayadapter for displaying and storing the data that the state of the adapter is not saved? Should i initiate my adapter in onCreate()?

Comment: hi jack i guess so, because i had a nullpointer exception to my adapter when i changed my orientation. What may be the reason that my adapter not recreate?

Comment: Hm. I'm using code from the Notes sample that comes with the API to populate a ListView with items from my database. That doesn't get destroyed upon changing the orientation. Maybe you're creating the ArrayAdapter in the "wrong place"? I.e., code that gets called not only creating the Activity by also upon changing the orientation? I can't imagine that the Activity should be destroyed and recreated upon reorienting the screen...

Comment: Hi Thorsten: an orientation change by default will cause an Activity to be destroyed, see: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges

Joejy: perhaps there is some data that you should be persisting in the onSaveInstanceState() of your activity and unpacking in the onRestoreInstanceState method? See the Activity documentation for more info.

Comment: does onSaveInstanceState() allows me to save non name-value pair stuff like objects ?

Answer (score -5):

Please put this code in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: thats awful hack, better learn how to store data on configuration changes!