# How to save ArrayAdapter in onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

I am doing a messenger app and for the message history I created a ListView with ArrayAdapter. I have a service that do the messaging activities, so supposedly it should receive a message even when the user is interacting with something else. However when I return to the app after pressing the home button I get an empty list view which is a bizarre thing for my app. H tried saving the Adapter in onsavingInstance but it's not working because it's not serialzable. please help me with that how could I preserve my list view. below is some patches of my code.

```java
// Array adapter for the conversation thread
private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;

private ListView mConversationView;
// Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread

mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

/** 
 * save the listView 

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("mArrayAdapter",  (Serializable) mConversationArrayAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(this, "History saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 */


public void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onStart();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");
   // if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  //    mConversationArrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mArrayAdapter");
  //  }
    setupChat();
}
```

Comment: Please format your code... it is not in a code block.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340838/android-how-do-i-preserve-the-data-in-my-arrayadapter-listview-when-change-orie check my answer here, I had the same problem

Answer (score -1):

`onSaveInstanceState` is not a place to save persistent data... in fact, it might not even be called.

I suggest you populate your `ArrayAdapter` in `onResume` and save it in `onPause`.

Comment: if onSaveInstanceState is not called, it's null in onCreate, so if you use onSaveInstanceState you have to test if it's null in onCreate, and if it is, populate the list from scratch. If you want to persist data, it's best to persist it when it changes. If your data doesn't change often, you don't want to save everything in onPause().

Comment: @Christine, So would you suggest saving the data immediately, each time a chat message is received?

Comment: The problem is how to save the ArrayAdapter in a bundle when I cast it to a serialized I have to acknowledge unchecked casting operation. I am not sure this the right way to save it. any other ideas ?

Comment: Would anyone help me please because I can't carry on my app without saving the listview. It will be nonsense to lose all the conversation history as soon as the user interact with another application.please help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in saving data onSaveInstanceState in fact if you data needs to be commited until a explicit action you should do it like so. in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)  save your parcelable array list of your items and then in onCreate check if savedInstanceState is not null and retrieve your saveddata. This is very handy approach

Comment: @Necronet `onSaveInstanceState()` is not guaranteed to be called, so it is not a good place to save _persistent_ data. See the note in [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState) on the developer site. If all you want to do is save UI state associated with the adapter, then sure, overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` would be fine.

Comment: If it's persistent data agree but in case it is data that need to be temprary save. (Scroll position, selected value, calculated value that do not yet need to be commited. I would say saveInstanceState is a good place to put it, if we are talking about real persisten data like something the user would need in the long run then try regular persistent strategy http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html