# ViewPager repeats same data for All pages and adding only 50 pages out of 500 pages

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

**ViewPager repeats same data for All pages and adding only 50 pages out of 500 pages**

**i m fetching All data from sqlite db (500 data items) but viewpager shows only one item and when flip the page it repeat the same one  item for all pages  what i m doing wrong?**
**second problem**

> i have 500 items in data base it means viewpager must add 500 pages for items but it adds only 50 pages

**code is below**

**class**

```
    package "";

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by name on 26-Mar-16.
 */
public class Test extends Activity {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<String> testContactName = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);


        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.testvp);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        getAllContacts();





    }

    public void getAllContacts() {
        DatabaseHelper dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();

        String query = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME;

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for (int c = 0; c < cursor.getCount(); c++) {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"));
                String count= String.valueOf(cursor.getCount());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), count , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                testContactName.add(name);
                //  testContactName.notifyAll();

                Log.i("Name: " + "" + "---", name);

            }mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        cursor.close();

    }



    private class MyAdapter  extends PagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return testContactName.size();

        }
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View collection, Object object) {

            return object == collection;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, null);

            String p= String.valueOf(position)+1;
           TextView pagenumber;
            pagenumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_test1);

            try {
                pagenumber.setText(testContactName.get(Integer.parseInt(p)));

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            ( collection).addView(view);
            return view;

        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            ( collection).removeView((View) view);

            (collection).getChildCount();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
}
```

**test xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/testvp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

**test1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/tv_test1"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not advancing the cursor in the for loop. That is why, it keeps adding the first item.

```
cursor.moveToNext();
```

Comment: When you flip, the activity is stopped and started all over. That is why it might be slow, it will reread all the values from the database. If you don't want that, you should look into handling the orientation change yourself. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340838/android-how-do-i-preserve-the-data-in-my-arrayadapter-listview-when-change-orie